# Underscore.js find unique values in array of objects; Return unique items and their count

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, unique

I am using _underscore.js to find all unique items in an array, but I can't figure out how to also get the number of unique items returned.

```
_PERSONARRAY = [{name:"tom",age:7}{name:"john",age:9}{name:"becky",age:2}{name:"sam",age:7}]

_UNIQUEAGEARRAY = _.chain(_PERSONARRAY).map(function(person) { return person.age }).uniq().value();
```

In this case _UNIQUEAGEARRAY will equal:

```
[7,9,2]
```

What I actually need returned is something like:

```
[{uniqueAge:7,numberOfPeople:2}{uniqueAge:9,numberOfPeople:1}{uniqueAge:2,numberOfPeople:1}]
```

Thanks for help.  Also, I'm assuming _underscore.js is quick at doing this??  If it's stupid slow tell me cause I'd be open to other solutions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `countBy` function:

```
_UNIQUEAGEARRAY = _.countBy(_PERSONARRAY, "age");
```

It produces the result:

```
{"2":1,"7":2,"9":1}
```

JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4J2SX/

Comment: Then you can simply run it through map to get it in the object structure you wanted (updated at http://jsfiddle.net/4J2SX/2/ )

Comment: @howard suppose I have this array of objects: [{couponid: 500 locationid: 10 },{couponid: 600 locationid: 15 }, { couponid: 500 locationid: 10 }, { couponid: 500 locationid: 20 } ] Using the solution given by you, I got an array of Unique coupon ids, with counts for each unique coupon id; it was the most concise anwer I found after lot of searhcing;Can you please tell, now how can i get, for each unique couponid, how many unique location ids ? ie in the above couponid 500 would have 2, and couponid 600 would have 1. Shall I post this as a separate question ?

Answer (score 82):

A nice solution is to use the optional iterator function to underscore's `uniq` function:

```
let people = [
  {name: "Alice", age: 21}, 
  {name: "Bob", age: 34},
  {name: "Caroline", age: 21}
];
_.uniq(people, person => person.age);
```

Docs: http://underscorejs.org/#uniq

Answer (score 1):

You can use underscore's groupBy if you want (might not be a good idea for a large dataset since it keeps a list of all the grouped items)

Example:

```
var d = _.groupBy(_PERSONARRAY, function(p){ 
    return p.age;
});
```

If you want to map this to your exact format try doing a map after the groupBy:

```
var x = _.map(d, function(people, age) {   
    return {uniqueAge: age,  numberOfPeople: people.length};   
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jsgkC/2/

Comment: Note: groupBy, countBy, indexBy all use the same "group" function internally so I don't know if one is that much better than the other from a performance point of view. You can see the annotated source here: http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html

Answer (score 0):

`groupBy` function is useful.

```
_personsList = [{name:"anjo",age:5},{name:"george",age:3},{name:"jack",age:5}];
_uniqAgeList = _.groupBy(_personsList, "age");
```

will produce output

```
{
    "3":[{"name":"george","age":3}],
    "5":[{"name":"anjo","age":5},{"name":"jack","age":5}]
}
```

jsfiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/4J2SX/199/